# what should a 2D RPG resolution be on a phone?

Tags: android, game-engine, screen-resolution

This is a quick question, but I am making a 2D RPG for both android and desktop. The thing is, is I am using 32x32px sprites. **How does Androids scaling work, is it able to adjust to very dynamic resolution changes, and still draw an image near or exactly the how it should?** I have never written an app for a phone before. I am afraid if I make the resolution in the game too high, the phone users wont be able to see the squares very well

1 Square = 32x32px
For example, my current grid layout is 40x23 Squares which equals about 1280x736

The other resolution im using is 24x15 Squares which is equal too about 768x480

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android supports screen resolutions from 320 x 240 to 3840 x 2160, so there is no single resolution that you can choose, you have to support multiple resolutions and densities. For starters you may want to read [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html).

Comment: This answer, opened my eyes, to so many different possibilities. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is too have a dynamic resolution that changes depending on the users screen size